# Salesforce Sharing settings for price book shows option as "Use". How its different form Public View and Public read write?

Tags: security, sharing

Salesforce Sharing settings for price book shows option as "No Access", "View Only" & "Use". How "Use" is different form "View only" and Public read write?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ViewOnly" means  users can view and report on price books . But where as "Use" means users can add any product within that price book to an opportunity.We don't have "Public read write" access on PriceBook Object. Please refer the below screenshot for the same.

[image]

Please refer the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5) for the same